# Failed to convert Multipartfile toString()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, multipart

I have the following controller that handles a form for adding a officer to the database.

```
//Add new officer to the database.
@RequestMapping(value = "/add_officer", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String addOfficer(@ModelAttribute Officer officer, Model model,
        @RequestParam (value = "dateFrom") String dateFrom,
        @RequestParam (value = "dateTo") String dateTo,
        @RequestParam (value = "photo") MultipartFile photo) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, SerialException, SQLException, ParseException {
    
    //Sets the officer photo.
    officer.setPhoto("data:image/png;image/jpeg;image/bmp;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo.getBytes()));
    officerService.addOfficer(officer);
    
    return "redirect:/officers";
}
```

Each officer has a profile picture associated with it. I don't know if it is the best practice, but what I do is to take the photo by `@RequestParam (value = "photo") MultipartFile photo)`, then I get the `String` representation of the `bytes` and I add `data:image/png;image/jpeg;image/bmp;base64` in front of the bytes. The product of this conversion is stored in the database.

As I said I am not sure if this is the best practice, but it gives me the ability to load and show photos from the database without any further conversion.

However, the problem occurs when I add another `@ModelAttribute` called `Holidays`. If I modify my controller to look like this -

```
    //Add new officer to the database.
@RequestMapping(value = "/add_officer", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String addOfficer(@ModelAttribute Officer officer, 
        @ModelAttribute Holiday holiday, Model model,
        @RequestParam (value = "dateFrom") String dateFrom,
        @RequestParam (value = "dateTo") String dateTo,
        @RequestParam (value = "photo") MultipartFile photo) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, SerialException, SQLException, ParseException {
    
    //Sets the officer photo.
    officer.setPhoto("data:image/png;image/jpeg;image/bmp;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo.getBytes()));
    officerService.addOfficer(officer);
    
    return "redirect:/police_officers";
}
```

Then I get thrown the following error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='officer'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'officer' on field 'photo': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@53bfe284]; codes [typeMismatch.officer.photo,typeMismatch.photo,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [officer.photo,photo]; arguments []; default message [photo]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'photo'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'photo': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

If I remove the line  `@ModelAttribute Holiday holiday` everything works fine. The moment I add it the error above is thrown. I am not sure how to resolve this and a little help would be appreciated!

Comment: `MultipartFile.toString` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @M.Deinum I haven't used `MultipartFile.toString`, what I actually used is `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo.getBytes()))`

Comment: If you look at the error it isn't even about that part. The issue is in your form submit, you should either have a dedicated form without the `photo` field and convert manually in your controller OR create a converter that does the conversion. Currently it isn't even reaching the controller.